# Filter RDD of tuples from another list of tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, tuples, rdd

I am currently working with Spark and Scalacheck and I am trying to filter a RDD[(A,Long)] **( where A is a register read from an Avro file and Long is obtained from the zipWithUniqueId() function )** from a sample out of that same RDD stored in a buffer.

My intention is to test some properties on that sample and once it fails, test that property again in a sample from that RDD which does not contains any of the values sampled before.
I am storing the rdd in a var so i can reassign it once i filter it.
My code goes like this :

```
val samplingSeed = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextLong()
val sampled = rdd.takeSample(withReplacement = false, bufferSize, samplingSeed)
val buffer: JQueue[(A, Long)] = new JConcurrentLinkedQueue[(A, Long)]

//Sampled as Array converts to queue
for (i <- 0 to sampled.length - 1)
 buffer.add(sampled(i).asInstanceOf[(A, Long)])

//rdd is assigned to a var for persistence
//filter here and leave out all the tuples in buffer based in the 
//Long  value in each tuple
 rdd= rdd.filter{foo}
```

How could i achieve this?

Comment: you can broadcast set of your sampled  ids, and check in filter if id is this set: `val ids = sc.broadcast(buffer.toSet.map(_._2)); rdd.filter(v => !ids.value.contains(v._2))`

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks

Comment: you're welcome, I've created answer. accept it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, filtering by set can be done using broadcast variable:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 10).toSeq)
val ids = sc.broadcast(Set(1, 2, 3))
rdd.filter(v => !ids.value.contains(v)).collect()
res1: Array[Int] = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```